# Flashing screen with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I had a dual boot which had Ubuntu 14.04 with the latest Nvidia driver installed, so far, so good. I formatted my hard drive and reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, but after I installed the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver I got a flickering screen, the same as in the video at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xVhGhCZBzk

I've tried reinstalling three times and the same thing happened. Before I had everything installed without any graphics bug. I need help to see what is happening. Could it be the iso that I'm using? I also tried the kernels 3.17, 3.18 and 3.19, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: What is the model of your nvidia card?

Comment: Qual é a saída do comando: `ubuntu-drivers devices`?

Answer (score 1):

Try going into CompizConfig Settings Manager and searching for `workarounds`.

Click on the only result:

[image]

then scroll down to the bottom and select the **Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint** check box:

[image]

Close CompizConfig and reboot and see if this helps.

This resolved a screen flicker I was having with my NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti, it's a known bug with NVIDIA drivers that's been around since 8.04.

I also did [a blog post](https://sudodblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/31/ubuntu-tech-snippet-12-fix-the-nvidia-screen-flicker-bug-in-ubuntu/) that goes over the entire process in more detail and provides some links.

Comment: I'm impressed!  :-)